# Rails 3. How to perform a "where" query by a virtual attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have two models: ScheduledCourse and ScheduledSession.

```
scheduled_course has_many scheduled_sessions

scheduled_session belongs_to scheduled_course
```

ScheduledCourse has a virtual attribute...

```
def start_at
  s = ScheduledSession.where("scheduled_course_id = ?", self.id).order("happening_at ASC").limit(1)
  s[0].happening_at
end
```

... the start_at virtual attribute checks all the ScheduledSessions that belongs to the ScheduledCourse and it picks the earliest one. So `start_at` is the date when the first session happens.

Now I need to write in the controller so get only the records that start today and go into the future. Also I need to write another query that gets only past courses.

I can't do the following because `start_at` is a virtual attribute

```
@scheduled_courses = ScheduledCourse.where('start_at >= ?', Date.today).page(params[:page])

@scheduled_courses = ScheduledCourse.where('start_at <= ?', Date.today)

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: start_at: SELECT  "scheduled_courses".* FROM "scheduled_courses"  WHERE (start_at >= '2012-03-13') LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't perform SQL queries on columns that aren't in the database. You should consider making this a real database column if you intend to do queries on it instead of a fake column; but if you want to select items from this collection, you can still do so. You just have to do it in Ruby.

```
ScheduledCourse.page(params).find_all {|s| s.start_at >= Date.today}
```

Comment: In the console it works, but in the web app it breaks kaminari, I get `undefined method `current_page' for #<Array:0x00000006409bc8>`

Answer (score 3):

Veraticus is right; You cannot use virtual attributes in queries.

However, I think you could just do:

```
ScheduledCourse.joins(:scheduled_sessions).where('scheduled_courses.happening_at >= ?', Date.today)
```

It will join the tables together by matching ids, and then you can look at the 'happening_at' column, which is what your 'start_at' attribute really is.

Disclaimer: Untested, but should work.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this would be solved by a subquery ( the subquery being to find the earliest date first).  If so, perhaps the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483407/subqueries-in-activerecord) might help point in a useful direction...