# Rails select subquery (without finder_sql, if possible)

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, subquery

I have an model called Object (doesn't really matter what it is)

It has a default price (column is called "price").

And then there is a Schedule object that allows to override the price for specific dates.

I want to be able to determine the MINIMUM price (which is by definition the MINIMUM between the default and "current" price) during the SQL-query just in order to be able to ORDER BY the calculated minimum price

I want to make my search query as efficient as possible and I was wondering if I can
do something like that:

```
Object.select("id AS p_id, id, (SELECT MIN(`schedules`.`price`) FROM `schedules` WHERE `schedules`.`object_id` = p_id`) AS objects.min_price").limit(5)
```

But, it generates an odd SQL that looks like this:

```
SELECT `objects`.`id` AS t0_r0, `objects`.`title` AS t0_r1, `objects`.`created_at` AS t0_r2, `objects`.`updated_at` AS t0_r3, `objects`.`preferences` AS t0_r4 ........ (a lot of columns here) ... ` WHERE `objects`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4 ....)
```

---

So, as you can see it doesn't work. First of all - it loads all the columns from the objects table, and second of all - it looks horrible.

The reason why I don't want to use finder_sql is that I have a lot of optional parameters and stuff, so using the AR::Relation object is highly preferred prior to fetching the results themselves.

In addition to abovementioned, I have a lot of records in the DB, and I think that loading them all into the memory is not a good idea and that is the main reason why I want to perform this subquery - just to filter-out as many records as possible.

Can someone help me how to do it more efficiently ?

Comment: Check your syntax, you have a few unbalanced parentheses and backticks in your SQL.

Comment: @PinnyM I was just copy-pasting really fast, so sorry about that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can make this easier if you generate the subquery separately and use a join instead of a correlated subquery:

```
subquery = Schedule.select('MIN(price) as min_price, object_id')
                   .group(:object_id)
                   .to_sql
Object.joins("JOIN (#{subquery}) schedules ON objects.p_id = schedules.object_id")
      .select('objects.*, schedules.min_price')
      .limit(5)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I cannot check it right now, but will it work with additional "joins" ?

Comment: Sure, just add them after the join string, comma separated

Comment: I've ment something like this:
Object.joins("(#{subquery}) schedules ON objects.p_id = schedules.object_id").joins(:tags).select('objects.*, schedules.min_price).limit(5)

Will this work ? :)

Comment: Certainly. You can chain multiple `joins` statements together, so this should work just fine.

Comment: Hi again. I've got a chance to try out your code and it does not work. 
It generates following SQL:
SELECT objects.*, schedules.min_price FROM `objects` (SELECT MIN(price) AS min_price, object_id FROM `schedules` GROUP BY object_id) schedules ON objects.id = schedules.object_id LIMIT 5

Do you know how to fix it ? :)

Comment: I forgot the word 'JOIN' before the subquery - try it now.

Comment: I've figured it our myself. Works. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: This is great. Splitting the subquery is the way to go.