# SELECT MIN (MAX) after SELECTING MIN value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max, min

I have two tables: **items** and **prices**  (one-to-many)

Each item has a *default price*, but this price can be overriden in this second table (under some circumstances).

Firstly I had a problem of fetching all the items and pre-calculate the MINIMUM PRICE - MIN between default and its overriding current price (if any ?).

You can see it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f31d5/25

Luckily, it was solved, thanks to stackoverflow (you can see it here: [Rails select subquery (without finder_sql, if possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556733/rails-select-subquery-without-finder-sql-if-possible)), but now I have similar kind of a problem!

Once I have all the items selected, can I determine the absolute MIN (or MAX) price AMONG the newly calculated field (**min_price**) ?

Of course I've tried something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f31d5/26

But, it did not work. Is there any smart SQL-true way to get these values ?

For this particular scenario in SQLFiddle it should return **5** (MIN), or **500** (MAX)

Of course I could have selected it straight-away from pricing table like this:

> SELECT MIN(price) FROM prices;

But, I cannot rely on it, since item's default price might be lower and this way I cannot check it (I think, *SELECT MIN/MAX* does not work with *JOIN* or *GROUP BY*).

And also one thing to be aware of - I'm writing this for my search system and this is just a small part of it, so, "WHERE"-clause is pretty important there as well, because NOT all items are actually involved.

Is there any SMART way (SQL-way) I can solve this problem?

P.S Temporarily I've solved the problem simply by making a query that orders by min_price (ASC/DESC) and applying LIMIT 1 and then gathering the needed value from the item record itself, but I'm very unhappy with this solution, so I've decided to ask about it here.

Thanks

**P.P.S** Totally forgot to mention, that there is no way I can avoid this SQL-query, because I have a pagination system that actually appends LIMIT X, OFFSET Y. So, I need to select the value GLOBALLY, not just for a particular page!

Comment: Do you want one row with the smallest price across all items?  Or the lowest price for each item?

Comment: One row with the smallest MIN_PRICE, that was calculated one step before that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the second call to `min()`.  I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT LEAST(IFNULL(MIN(prices.price),
                    items.default_price),
             default_price) as min_price
FROM items LEFT OUTER JOIN
      prices
      ON prices.item_id = items.id
GROUP BY items.id;
```

If you want the lowest price across all items, you can remove the `group by` clause.  However, I think a subquery is clearer about the intention:

```
select min(min_price)
from (SELECT LEAST(IFNULL(MIN(prices.price),
                          items.default_price),
                   default_price) as min_price
      FROM items LEFT OUTER JOIN
            prices
            ON prices.item_id = items.id
      GROUP BY items.id
     ) p;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do. 
Mainly because of the pagination system I have. 
So, I need a pure-SQL solution.

Comment: Works like a charm! Superb! Thanks! BTW, can you explain, why do you need a "p" literal at the end of the query ?

Comment: @Dmitri the "p" literal is there because every table must have unique name. In this case, the subquery is (temporary) table.