# How to adapt a query to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to adapt a query to ruby on rails, inside the query there is a subquery with a from that I do not know how I can adapt it to rails. The original query is as follows:

```
SELECT B.Codigo, C.NombreCorto, B.Descripcion, B.HI, B.latitude, B.longitude, C.Direccion, ISNULL((SELECT SUM(TOTAL) 
FROM Venta 
WHERE RutaId=B.RutaId AND DiaO=B.DiaO AND CodCliente=B.Codigo AND Cancelada='0' AND TOTAL>0),0) AS TOTAL 
FROM BitacoraTiempos B LEFT JOIN Clientes C ON C.IdCli=B.Codigo 
WHERE B.RutaId='161' AND B.DiaO='893' 
ORDER by B.HI
```

And this is what I have adapted so far:

```
  def self.search_gps_venta(params)

    query = select('[bitacoratiempos].Codigo,[bitacoratiempos].RutaId,[bitacoratiempos].Descripcion,[bitacoratiempos].HI,[bitacoratiempos].latitude,[clientes].NombreCorto AS c_nombre,[clientes].Direccion AS c_direccion')
         .joins('left join clientes ON bitacoratiempos.Codigo=clientes.IdCli')
         .where("(bitacoratiempos.RutaId = :rutaId or :rutaId = '') AND (bitacoratiempos.DiaO = :diaO or :diaO = '') AND (bitacoratiempos.IdEmpresa = :idempresa)",{rutaId: params[:search], diaO: params[:diaO]})
    query

  end
```

And in the controller I call it this way:

```
  def busqueda_gps_venta
    @ventas = Bitacoratiempo.search_gps_venta(params)

    respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    end
  end
```

How can I include inside my rails query this part of the original query:

```
  SELECT B.Codigo, C.NombreCorto, B.Descripcion, B.HI, B.latitude, B.longitude, C.Direccion, ISNULL((SELECT SUM(TOTAL) 
FROM Venta 
WHERE RutaId=B.RutaId AND DiaO=B.DiaO AND CodCliente=B.Codigo AND Cancelada='0' AND TOTAL>0),0) AS TOTAL
```

Comment: Firstly - I notice that your adaptation... is not actually quite the same query as the original SQL you have - this is confusing and makes it more difficult to figure out how to help you - there's a group in there that isn't present in the original query, and there are more where conditions... are you mangling together the query with the subquery somehow? You shouldn't need to do that. your rails query will have the same structure (roughly) as your original query...

Comment: Secondly: see if this one can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556733/rails-select-subquery-without-finder-sql-if-possible

Comment: @TarynEast Thanks for answer. Sorry, I already updated my post. My problem is that in the original query there is a subquery where a "FROM" is included to another table called "Venta", how can I do it? Is there any way I can use the original query in rails without adapting it?

Comment: Yes... have a look at the answer in the other question that I linked to. Also - you can just pass big strings of SQL to rails...