# Most recent prices and will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, will-paginate

I have two models `Product` and `Price`. `Product` can have multiple prices, each with different `created_at`, so at any time I can have product's price history.

I want to display list of products with most recent price next to each product, and use will_paginate to paginate 10 products per page.

I wrote something like this in my `ProductsController`:

```
@products = Product.includes(:prices).references(:prices).
  select('DISTINCT ON (products.id) *').
  order('products.id, prices.created_at ASC').
  paginate(page: params[:page])
```

When I check `.to_sql` for this query, I see that will_paginate adds `WHERE \"products\".\"id\" IN (2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7)`, and instead of 10 products I get 5.

When I try:

```
Product.includes(:prices).references(:prices).
      select('DISTINCT ON (products.id) *').
      order('products.id, prices.created_at ASC').limit(10).pluck(:id)
```

I get `=> [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7]`

Any idea how can I change it to get 10 products with access to most recent price?

Comment: You need the most recent 10 prices, in your case the most recent 10 prices are duplicates and only five are unique. The `Distinct ' in your query does remove the five distinct ones.

Comment: You could remove Distinct and you will get only five.

Comment: How ids can have duplicates ? They should be uniqe because they are primary keys.

Comment: it's a join operation, so you can have multiple ids

Comment: try to group the join result by product id `GROUP BY "products.id".`

Comment: Tricky query... take a look at this entry https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556733/rails-select-subquery-without-finder-sql-if-possible

Comment: does your models implement the `has_many` relation between `products` and `prices` ?, if yes the i think `Products.include(:prices).order("created_at").limit(10)` will be enough

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to do this with this:

```
@products = Product.
  select('DISTINCT ON(products.id) products.*, prices.value as recent_price').
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN prices ON products.id = prices.product_id').
  order('products.id ASC, prices.created_at DESC').
  paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Comment: I don't think DISTINCT is ever going to get you what you need here... you really need a correlated sub query to get what you need. Try writing it in straight SQL first and then try to back into that in rails (or create a VIEW tied to a model)

Comment: can you post the models you have for both models ?

Comment: @BrettGreen, it's `DISTINCT ON` and it works only in Postgres I think.

Comment: Interesting... didn't notice that. It's like WITH TIES in SQL Server.