# Returning a list with ActiveRecord query interface

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My `Program` class has_many `Patients`
and `Patient` class has a field like `salary`

And the json I pass to JBuilder with `respond_to :json  , respond_with(@org)` is like this:

```
@org = Org.includes(programs: [{hospitals: :nurses}, :patients]).find(params[:id])
```

Well now if my database has 200 programs that meed the `org_id = params[:id]` condition it will return them all. BUT this is Not what I want. I want to tell it to return "5" programs and those "five" programs that the "salary" field of their :'patients" table is the highest.

How can I implement this limitation in active record query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
Program.includes([{hospitals: :nurses}, :patients]).where("organization_id = ?", params[:id]).order("patients.salary desc").limit(5)
```

---

Or you can do:

```
@program_ids = Program.select("id").includes([{hospitals: :nurses}, :patients]).where("organization_id = ?", params[:id]).order("patients.salary desc").limit(5)
@org = Org.includes(programs: [{hospitals: :nurses}, :patients]).where("programs.id = ?", program_ids.collect(&:id)).find(params[:id])
```

You can also refactor with a subquery in one step (still 2 queries), by checking this question:

[subqueries in activerecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483407/subqueries-in-activerecord)

I'm not sure if you can get that information in just one single query

Comment: we can take out the "where" part of your code because Org.includes with that .find(params[:id]) is taking care of that .

Comment: and what if the next condition was to also list "bottom 5 nurses" . For simplicity lets' say they also have a field called salary.So: Top 5 patients and bottom 5 nurses.  
Thanks for help.

Comment: Ok, I added the query for returning just the top 5 programs. If you still want the Organization you can put the organization on the top and remove the where clause.

Comment: You need two different queries, one to list the top sallaries for patients, and another for the lowest five different nurses.
So the second one will just have a order("nurses.sallary asc").limit(5)
If you want to mix multiple order conditions, you can still do it by using a comma, ie. order("patients.sallary desc, pattients.first_name asc")

Comment: And the problem with the query is that if you put the Organization at the top of the query, the limit(5) will apply on the Organization and not on the Program, so you better get the first programs with one query and with a second query you get the Organization and filter the ids of the programs with the result of the first query, or use subselects

Comment: :( getting so complicated, is there a way with like "scope" to do this sorting and limit 5 stuff in the MODELS of those two tables?