# Re-writing SQL query and translating to ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, activerecord

I am running into some difficulty re-writing a SQL query and translating it to an `ActiveRecord` query.

Say I have a table `resources`, which provides a list of resources identified by `id` (and containing other attributes).

Say I also have a table `reservation_slots`, which lists reservations on these resources as one hour slots, with attributes: `id`, `start_datetime`, `reservation_id`, and `resource_id` (which references `resources.id`). A multi-hour reservation on a resource will have multiple rows in this table.

I want to retrieve a list of all "unavailable" time slots: `start_datetimes` where all resources (in the `resources` table) are already reserved. I can retrieve such a list with the following SQL:

```
select start_datetime 
from reservation_slots
where not exists (
  select r.id 
  from resources r 
  where r.id not in (
    select resource_id
    from reservation_slots rs
    where rs.start_datetime = reservation_slots.start_datetime
  )
)
```

Is there a simpler or more efficient way to express this query? How would I write this as an `ActiveRecord` query without a lot of raw SQL in the where clause?

Comment: Do look for [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483407/subqueries-in-activerecord) before asking

Comment: Thanks for the link, @hd1, but it doesn't answer the first part of my question (re-writing the SQL), and I am familiar with the techniques mentioned for nesting AR queries. I guess [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place for this question.