# Is there a simpler way to return a belongs_to relation of an ActiveRecord result set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models:

```
Answers:
  belongs_to: user

User:
  has_many: answers
```

Is there a way in Ruby or Rails to do the following in one go instead of creating an array and pushing the needed object into it?

```
def top_experts
    answers = Answer.where(some constraints)

    users = []
    answers.each do |answer|
        users << answer.user
    end
    users
end
```

Comment: There's probably a better way to do this. First, you need to decide how many votes are needed to qualify a `User` as a `top_user`. Then, this query should really be executed on the `User` model, not the `Vote` model.

Comment: @zeantsoi Thanks! It turned out to be more complex than I thought -- I was incorrectly using the wrong model to quality a user as top expert. Turns out I need to get users' questions and answers posted and tally up their votes.

Comment: Fair enough... care to rephrase the question?

Comment: Just updated the question... it's more of the Ruby knowledge I'm missing here. Creating an array and pushing the needed objects into it to return seems inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user `joins`

```
def top_experts
    Answer.where(some constraints).includes(:user).collect{|x| x.user}
    # Will return an Array of users
end
```

**EDIT:**

Use `includes` for eager loading. It will reduce the no of queries executed to get user.

Comment: I don't need to join -- the rails model relations already provide `vote.user` for each of those vote objects... just need a way to return an active record result set of just the users, not the votes.

Comment: Im aware but you can use `vote.user` only with instances or objects, but in your question you specified the class `Vote` where you can only use `joins` to retrieve the association

Comment: That's awesome regarding the `includes` eager loading! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use a select clause to select what should be returned along with the where clause

> > Vote.select(user_id).where(some contraints)

Answer (score 0):

Use sub-query to get users:

```
User.where( :id => Answer.where(some constraints).select(:user_id) )
```

Refer: [subqueries in activerecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483407/subqueries-in-activerecord)