# Collecting records via a string and making arrays of those records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a loop that looks like this:

```
<% current_user.brand.templates.each do |template| %>
  <li><%= link_to(template.label, new_templated_document_path(template)) %></li>
<% end %>
```

A `Template` can have a category, but it's just a string and not an association. Is there a way to collect the `Templates` here based on category and sub-menu them accordingly? It feels like I'll have to build an array for each category in the model or something. Something like this:

```
categories = []
Template.categories.each do |c|
  category = []
  category << Template.where(category: c).all
  categories << category
end
categories
```

Feels pretty clumsy though. Any help?

**Update**

I've changed it to this:

```
@categories = {}
Template.first.categories.each do |c|
  @categories[c] = current_user.brand.templates.where(category: c)
end
```

But I can't seem to get the records into the hash. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can query the templates and group them by category, that would be much more easier

```
Template.all.group_by(&:category)
```

You will get a hash with key is the category and values are lists of templates

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5708897/979978) you can use something like `Template.where(category: Template.categories)`. You can also take a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions) where it is stated that:

```
Client.where(orders_count: [1,3,5])
```

will produce

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE (clients.orders_count IN (1,3,5))
```

Which I think is what you want.

Comment: That's far more elegant. Thanks for the hint!