# Get all records where the number of associated records is smaller than a certain number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model `Occurrence` that has many `Cleaners` through the joint table `Assignments`. The `Occurrence` model has a field `number_of_cleaners`.

How can I find all `Occurrences` using Active Record (or SQL, Postgres) where the number of assigned `Cleaners` is smaller than the number specified in `occurrences.number_of_cleaners`?

This query is to identify the `Occurrences` where we need to find more `Cleaners` to assign to the `Occurrence`).

```
class Occurrence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :cleaners, through: :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cleaner
  belongs_to :occurrence
end
```

Just as a side note, previously we just queried for each `Occurrence` that had no `Assignment` regardless of `occurrences.number_of_cleaners`. The query looked like this:

```
# Select future occurrences which do not have an assignment (and therefore no cleaners) and select one per job ordering by booking time
# The subquery fetches the IDs of all these occurrences
# Then, it runs another query where it gets all the IDs from the subquery and orders the occurrences by booking time
# See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8708460/1076279 for more information on how to perform subqueryes
subquery = Occurrence.future.where.not(id: Assignment.select(:occurrence_id).uniq).select('distinct on (job_id) id').order('occurrences.job_id', 'booking_time')
@occurrences = Occurrence.includes(job: :customer).where("occurrences.id IN (#{subquery.to_sql})").where.not(bundle_first_id: nil).select{ |occurrence| @current_cleaner.unassigned_during?(occurrence.booking_time, occurrence.end_time) }
```

Comment: Do you need all the cleaners of that occurrence based on that number, or you need all the occurrences?

Comment: I need all the occurrences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of joining the tables and doing query, You should implement `counter_cache` on your models as its more efficient and meant exactly for the purpose.

For more details, check out these links:

[Counter Cache in Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html)

[Three Easy Steps to Using Counter Caches in Rails](http://yerb.net/blog/2014/03/13/three-easy-steps-to-using-counter-caches-in-rails/)