# ActiveRecord model.update_column with subquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I want to update a column in a `Supply` model that updates with its stock based on a `sum` of a subset. The thing is that actually hits two queries to make it works.

```
total_stock = History.sum(:quantity) # first query
Supply.update_columns(stock: total_stock) # second query
```

Then, I tried to write a subquery so:

```
total_stock_subquery = mysubset.select(Arel.sql('SUM(quantity)')).to_sql
Supply.update_columns(stock: total_stock_subquery) # it should be only one query
```

But, `ActiveRecord` will replace the `total_stock_subquery` variable as a `string` inside the resulting `sql statement`, then query fails.

I tried to wrap the `total_stock_subquery` parameter inside an `Arel.sql` thinking that ActiveRecord will detect that the parameter is not a string, but `Arel.sql`, and would escape this as **raw sql**, but it didnt work.

```
Supply.update_columns(stock: Arel.sql(total_stock_subquery)) # dont work too
```

Then, do you know how can I pass an `sql subquery` as parameter for a column inside `.update_column`, o maybe how to tell `ActiveRecord` that some parameter should be treated as pure sql not as string?

I know I could write this update as raw sql but I think it would be off Rails style.

**EDIT:** Table definitions

**History**

- id: integer
- supply_id: reference
- quantity: decimal(9,2)

**Supply**

- id: integer
- product: string
- stock: decimal(9,2)

`class History
  belongs_to: supply
end`

`class Supply
   has_many: histories
end`

We use the **History** model to track in and out (positive for in, negative for out) of supplies, then the sum of the histories will be the current stock.

Of course I can implement an `after_save` on `History` model to update the stock when some `quantity` changes it, but for this example, Im implementing a "rebase" or "recalculate" method for all supplies stock, then I need to make the sum for each `Supply`.

Comment: are both queries done to the same model  to different models ?

Comment: can we know how the tables look like ?

Comment: the first query, the SUM, is maked to one model, and the second, the UPDATE, to another

Comment: I added the models definitions